# How to parse ipv6 address into "octets"?

Tags: c#, ipv6

I want to be able to parse ipv6 address into octets. Is there something similar to the following?

```
IPAddress.Parse(address).GetAddressBytes()[0];
IPAddress.Parse(address).GetAddressBytes()[1];
```

Comment: @L.B `GetAddressBytes()` already returns an array.

Comment: `GetAddressBytes()` works with IPv6 addresses as well... or is that not what you meant?

Comment: If I have an ipv4 address of: 1.2.3.4, GetAddressBytes()[0] will return 1.

If I have an ipv6 address of: 2001::1:2:3:4, GetAddressBytes()[0] will return 32.
How do I get the 2001?

Comment: 2001 can not fit to an octet.

Comment: @amirm: You're a little confuse, I think. See my amended answer below.

Comment: 32 is 0x20. An IPv6 address is written in hexadecimal, where every two hexadecimal characters are one byte. So for `2001::1:2:3:4` you'll get an array with 0x20 (=32), 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
IPAddress ipv6Addr = IPAddress.Parse("FE80::0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329") ;
byte[]    octets   = ipv6Addr.GetAddressBytes() ;

string text = String.Join( "," , octets.Select( x => string.Format("0x{0:X2}", x ) ) ) ;
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The above snippet writes this to the console:

```
0xFE,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,0xB3,0xFF,0xFE,0x1E,0x83,0x29
```

as you might expect.

**Edited to Note:** You might want to read up on how IPv6 addresses are represented as *text*:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1924

IPv4 addresses are a 32 bit integer (4 octets) in length and are represent in text using "dotted quad " notation: `x.x.x.x`, where each 'x' is the decimal value of the octet in question.

IPv6 addresses are 128 bits (16 octets in length). The canonical textual representation is as 8 16-bit integers shown in hexadecimal form, separated by colons: `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx`, though there are a number of ways to manipulate that so as to make the representation more compact.

To get what you appear to want from your comment, you'll need to take the array of 16 octets you get and convert each pair of octets into a `ushort`.

You should note though, that the textual represention is of the IP address in **network byte order** (big-endian, the only proper architecture, IMHO). Intel chips are little-endian. You'll need to take that into account. More on endianness and network byte order here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Hex octets was a bad example - everyone uses base-10, including the RFC's.  Here's a TLS certificate using IPv6 octets for example: https://[2606:4700:4700::1111]/ (load the page and view the certificate to see them).   It would have been nice to explain to him that the "20" in "2001" means 0x20, which is the number 32 (base 10) that he saw in his GetAddressBytes()[0] 
 array too...